# How can I most quickly append another column into a Matlab matrix?

Tags: matlab

So if tavg_curltau is a 360x159 double and I want to convert it into a 360x160 double, how would I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate matrices using `[]`. For example:

```
a = ones(360,159);
b = ones(360,1);
c = [a,b];
size(c)
ans =

   360   160
```

Answer (score 3):

You can append a column to a matrix using the horzcat() function, brackets, or the cat() function with dim=2. The first is fastest. Regardless, make sure that the column you are appending is the same height (in rows) as the matrix you are appending it to. Otherwise, you will get an error.

```
>> tic; a=ones(360,159); b=zeros(360,1); c=horzcat(a,b); toc
Elapsed time is 0.000323 seconds.
>> tic; a=ones(360,159); b=zeros(360,1); c=[a,b]; toc
Elapsed time is 0.000858 seconds.
>> tic; a=ones(360,159); b=zeros(360,1); c=cat(2,a,b); toc
Elapsed time is 0.001050 seconds.
>> tic; a=ones(360,159); b=zeros(359,1); c=horzcat(a,b); toc
Error using horzcat
CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.
```

Answer (score 1):

muultiply by the Identical (159X160) matrix I

Comment: +1 for a technically correct answer...